# why is the Cantor-Lebesgue function increasing

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I am trying to derive the fact that the function $F$ defined below is monotonically increasing. The only thing I can use is that the any member of the Cantor set has a ternary expansion involving only $0$'s and $2$'s. The function is defined as follows: Let $x\in[0,1]$ have ternary expansion $0.a_1a_2\cdots$. Define $N$ as the first index $n$ for which $a_n=1$ and set $N=\infty$ if none of the $a_n$ are $1$. Now let $F(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\frac{a_n}{2^{n+1}}+\frac{1}{2^N}$.

I have shown that $F$ is constant while on a particular middle third removed in the construction of the Cantor set $C$ so I am really interested in showing the increasing nature on $C$. Essentially therefore I wish to show that given $x=\sum \frac{a_n}{3^n}<\sum\frac{b_n}{3^n}=y$ we have $\sum\frac{a_n}{2^{n+1}}<\sum\frac{b_n}{2^{n+1}}$ on $C$. How do I establish that?

Thanks

Comment: Since on $C$ your $a_n$, $b_n$ are all zeroes and twos, try thinking of the relation you want to show as describing some binary expansions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that $a_n-b_n\in\{-2,0,2\}$.

Suppose that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n-b_n}{3^n}\gtrless0\tag{1}
$$
$(1)$ happens if and only if, for the smallest $n_0$ so that $a_{n_0}\not=b_{n_0}$, it is the case that $a_{n_0}\gtrless b_{n_0}$.

The claim above is true because
$$
\text{If }a_{n_0}>b_{n_0}\text{ then }\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n-b_n}{3^n}\ge\frac2{3^{n_0}}-\sum_{n>n_0}\frac2{3^n}=\frac1{3^{n_0}}\tag{2}
$$
$$
\text{If }a_{n_0}<b_{n_0}\text{ then }\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n-b_n}{3^n}\le-\frac2{3^{n_0}}+\sum_{n>n_0}\frac2{3^n}=-\frac1{3^{n_0}}\tag{3}
$$
If for the smallest $n_0$ so that $a_{n_0}\not=b_{n_0}$, it is the case that $a_{n_0}\gtrless b_{n_0}$, then
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n-b_n}{2^{n+1}}\gtreqless0\tag{4}
$$
This is because
$$
\text{If }a_{n_0}>b_{n_0}\text{ then }\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n-b_n}{2^{n+1}}\ge\frac1{2^{n_0}}-\sum_{n>n_0}\frac1{2^n}=0\tag{5}
$$
$$
\text{If }a_{n_0}<b_{n_0}\text{ then }\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n-b_n}{2^{n+1}}\le-\frac1{2^{n_0}}+\sum_{n>n_0}\frac1{2^n}=0\tag{6}
$$
So, if $x\gtrless y$, $F(x)\gtreqless F(y)$. We can't get strict increase since $F$ is constant on all the "middle-thirds" intervals.

Comment: Thanks. One small question though. What is the need of establishing  the inequality involving $\sum\frac{a_n-b_n}{3^n}$?

Comment: @Shahab: since that is $x-y$.

Comment: To show the increasing nature we start with $x<y$ in $C$ and attempt to prove $F(x)\le F(y)$. But if $x<y$ then it is obvious from the definition of ternary that $a_{n_0}<b_{n_0}$ and I don't understand why we need to consider all but the last inequality.

Comment: @Shahab: $(2)$ and $(3)$ are proof of the claim that $x>y$ *if and only if* the first differing base-three digit of $x$ is greater than the corresponding digit of $y$. Obviously, if all of the $a_n=b_n$ then $x=y$. However, if the first differing digit of $x$ is greater than the corresponding digit of $y$, then $x>y$ (the later digits cannot catch up). Likewise, if the first digit of $x$ is less than the corresponding digit of $y$, then $x< y$.

Comment: @Shahab: What $(2)$, $(3)$, and self-evidence show is
$$
\begin{align}
\text{first differing digit of $x$ is smaller}&\Rightarrow x< y\\
\text{all digits are equal}&\Rightarrow x=y\\
\text{first differing digit of $x$ is bigger}&\Rightarrow x>y
\end{align}
$$
Since *all* sequences fall into one of the categories on the left and the categories on the right do not overlap, we actually have *bijections* above (e.g. if $x< y$, then none of the other conditions on the left can hold because they imply $x=y$ or $x>y$), and this justifies the previous "if and only if" claim.

Comment: Can I ask one question? I think that the function $F(x)=\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{a_n}{2^{n+1}}+\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}2^{-n}$ For the inequality (6), why your $n_0$ is same as $N$? Also, for the first $n_0$ terms I can get the upper bound $-2^{-n_0}$. However, for the tail one, why do we have $\sum_{n>n_0}2^{-n-1}(a_n-b_n)\le \sum_{n>n_0}2^{-n}$? @robjohn♦

Comment: Or can we just say that $F(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} a_n2^{-n-1}+\sum_{N+1}^{\infty}2^{-n}\le \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} b_n2^{-n-1}+\sum_{N+1}^{\infty}2^{-n}=F(y)$?

Comment: Yes, my $n_0$ is $N$ from the question. $a_n-b_n\le2$. In your second comment, you cannot just ignore the lower order terms.

Comment: So how can we say $F(x)\le F(y)$? Here $n_0$ should be different from $N$, right? $n_0$ is the minimal so that $a_n\neq b_n$ but $N$ is the first index n
 for which $a_n=1$

Comment: Oh, I guess my $n_0$ is not the $N$ in the question. Sorry, it's been a while since I looked at this question. The question about $F(x)\le F(y)$ is what I attempted to show in $(5)$ and $(6)$.

Comment: Yes. But how to show that $F(x)=\sum a_n/2^{n+1}$? I think that $F(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}a_n/2^{n+1}+2^{-N}$..

Comment: The question is about $x,y\in C$. There, $N=\infty$ and $a_n,b_n\in\{0,2\}$. The middle thirds are where there is a $1$. $F$ simply moves anything in a middle third to the right end of the interval so that everything is in $C$ and then maps $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{3^n}$ to $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{2^{n+1}}$.